# Python - Filelisting, duplicate results

Tags: python, loops, directory, writetofile

I am new to Python and trying to make a script that reads a DIR and returns that DIR in a .txt file.

My code is:

```
import os
from os import walk
rootdir = "C:\\PythonTesting\\dirReader\\test"
fileslist = []
fileslisting=(fileslist)
pathout=(rootdir+"\\output\\")

#reqFileOutput=input("What do you want to call your output file.?")
reqFileOutput=("test") #temp file name for testing
OutputName=(reqFileOutput+".txt")

fileout = open(pathout+OutputName, "w") #wipes file if already exists
fileout.close()

def file_display(fileslist):
    print(fileslist)

    file=open(fileslist,"r")

    fileout = open(pathout+OutputName, "a")
    fileout.write(fileslist)


for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(rootdir):
    for file in files:
        filepath = subdir + os.sep + file
        if filepath.endswith(".txt"): 
            fileslist.append(filepath)
    for path in fileslist:
        file_display(path)    

input("\n\nExit?")
```

I have 2 files in my DIR with .txt 
 TEST.txt and 
 TEST2.txt

When I run this script, it lists these files 3 times, but I don't know why?
Next, I wanted it to write the list to a text file, when I do, it just writes them in the file one after the other, no spaces. 
How do I get them to list?

Comment: What does your program `print`?  Can you show the contents of your output file, and what you want it to be?

Comment: I ran your code and had no problems with the output listing the paths 3 times.  Are you sure that you don't have more than 3 files in that path?  I tried it with one file, two files, three files and it works fine.  getting it to print the paths on separate lines should be a simple thing to do.  Also finish the code for your exit prompt...Keep in mind that it is listing your 2 added files AND your Test file that holds the paths to those other two files...it will be seen in the folder as another path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your last loop is indented which means it's included in the outer `for` loop. As a result, it will run multiple times. Try this loop instead:

```
for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(rootdir):
    for file in files:
        filepath = subdir + os.sep + file
        # collect paths to *.txt files found
        if filepath.endswith(".txt"): 
            fileslist.append(filepath)

# print paths to all *.txt files found
for path in fileslist:
    file_display(path)
```

Comment: Thank you, I am still getting my head around the indentations and how they work. Only been using Python for about a month.